# ListView inside constraint view gets clipped and not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-constraintlayout

I have a listview inside my ConstraintLayout and I read its supposed to automatically be scrollable, but the list just gets cut-off at the bottom with more items left to be displayed and its not scrollable, I dont know if Im setting some atribute wrong or if I have to add something for listview to scroll??

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/special_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Today is:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="The date is:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/special_text_view"/>



     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oc_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="The day of the omer is:"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_text_view"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/oc_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    </ListView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry to all just realized the scrollbar was working it was just that the bottom navigation bar was clipping the bottom elements, but when I added more items it scrolled.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the chain, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/special_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Today is:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/date_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="The date is:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/oc_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/special_text_view" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oc_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="The day of the omer is:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_text_view" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/oc_text_view">
    </ListView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Dont really see what you changed

Comment: Does it work or not? (I changed quite a number of attributes.)

Comment: To anyone else wondering, the key here is `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` in the ListView

Answer (score 0):

While using ConstraintLayout you have to add constraints for constraintTop, constraintRight, constraintBottom, constraintLeft or constraintStart and constraintEnd. Please constraint all your four sides of constrant layout(or use Constraint Start or End). Then only it works as expected

```
use below code in list view:
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

For Reference:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: Hi just tried adding the missing constraints and updated the post still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

Here I'm populating 10 items in the ListView. See the attached result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.silambarasan.test.MainActivity"
>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/special_text_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:text="Today is:"
     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
     android:textSize="24sp"
     android:visibility="visible"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:text="The date is:"
     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
     android:textSize="24sp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/oc_text_view"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/special_text_view"
     />


  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/oc_text_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
     android:text="The day of the omer is:"
     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
     android:textSize="24sp"
     android:visibility="visible"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_text_view"
     />

  <ListView
     android:id="@+id/list_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
     app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
     >
  </ListView>

  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"
     />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image: results]

Comment: Hi Thanks I just added a comment to my question I realized it was working all along it just didnt have enough elements and was getting clipped by the nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

With using the `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`, you can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/special_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Today is:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="The date is:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/oc_text_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/special_text_view"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oc_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="The day of the omer is:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_text_view"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    >
</ListView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```